# UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents] overflow. Ignoring

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create `UITextField` dynamically then at click of textField trying to show picker view but some how getting the above mentioned error.
and it runs in loop error does not stop unless and until i stop the application.

**Code**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    if (textField.tag < 10) {


        if ([[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag] isEqualToString:@"Currency"])
        {



            [self showpicker:textField];



        }
        else if([[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag ] isEqualToString:@"Date" ])
        {



            [self showpicker:textField];


        }
        else if([[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag] isEqualToString:@"Text"])
        {



        }

    }
    else
    {


        [self showpicker:textField];


    }





}

-(void)showpicker:(UITextField *)textfield
{
      [textfield resignFirstResponder];

        if (textfield.tag >= 10 ) {

            currentTextField=textfield;
            pickerArray=arraycurrency;

            actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
            CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

            pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
            pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            pickerView.dataSource = self;
            pickerView.delegate = self;
            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

            UIToolbar *pickerToolbar;

            pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
            pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
            [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

            NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
            [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

            UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
            [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

            UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
            [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

            [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];

            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

            [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
            [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

            [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];




        }
        else if ([[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textfield.tag ] isEqualToString:@"Date" ])
        {

            [textfield resignFirstResponder];

            currentTextField=textfield;

            actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];


            pickerDateView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
            pickerDateView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
            pickerDateView.hidden = NO;
            pickerDateView.date = [NSDate date];
            pickerDateView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            pickerDateView.timeZone=[NSTimeZone localTimeZone];


            UIToolbar *pickerToolbar;

            pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
            pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
            [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

            NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
            [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

            UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
            [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

            UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
            [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

            [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];
            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerDateView];

            [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];


            [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];



        }
        else if ( [[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textfield.tag] isEqualToString:@"Text"])
        {

            [textfield becomeFirstResponder];

        }
        else if((textfield.tag==0 || textfield.tag==1 || textfield.tag==2 || textfield.tag==3 || textfield.tag==4) &&
            [[datatypeArray objectAtIndex:textfield.tag] isEqualToString:@"Currency"]);
        {

            [textfield becomeFirstResponder];

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following  describe  simple code for display `UIPickerView` when you Tapped on `UItextField`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
    {
      [self willDisplayPickerView];
    }
```

// Code of  `willDisplayPickerView` Method:

```
    - (void)willDisplayPickerView
      {

        // Init the picker view.
 pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

 // Set the delegate and datasource. Don't expect picker view to work
 // correctly if you don't set it.
 [pickerView setDataSource: self];
 [pickerView setDelegate: self];

 // Set the picker's frame. We set the y coordinate to 50px.
 [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 50.0f, pickerWidth, 200.0f)];

 // Before we add the picker view to our view, let's do a couple more
 // things. First, let the selection indicator (that line inside the
 // picker view that highlights your selection) to be shown.
 pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

 // Allow us to pre-select the third option in the pickerView.
 [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

 // OK, we are ready. Add the picker in our view.
 [self.view addSubview: pickerView];
    }
```